Store object array of product size and colors in mongo DB
I need to store object array of product size and colors.
Is it possible in mongo DB.(Because in ms sql it is not allowed).If so how the schema should be?.Sample object structure is shown below
{
color : "RGB or hexa value",
size : "3XL",
quantity: 54
}


See the insert examples in the official MongoDB docs.

After installing, import the mongoose package into a module, lets say Product.js.
And then write this code.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  color: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  size: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0
  }
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product; 

After that you can import this module to other module where needed to perform the CRUD operation based on Product model.
And also you can insert the data that is shared in your code.
You can check how to insert data here in the official docs.
You can also check Mongoose-schema related official docs here for more information.

I just needed to add another attribute for existing model as a single attribute.(simply to store al these details in a object and have multiple objects).Anyway Thanks man!.
